# send an email with attachment using a form

Tags: laravel

I can't understand what the problem may be:
I state that the code without the part of the attachment works

```
  function submit(Request $request)
 {

$this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'file' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx'
    ]);

  $data = array(
'name_data'  => $request->name,
'cognome_data' => $request->cognome,
'luogo_data'  => $request->luogo,
'date_data' => $request->date,
'telefono_data' => $request->telefono,
'email_data' => $request->email,
'citta_data' => $request->citta,
'provincia_data' => $request->provincia,
'studio_data' => $request->studio,
'lingua_data' => $request->lingua,
'livello_data' => $request->livello,
'lingua2_data' => $request->lingua2,
'livello2_data' => $request->livello2,
'file_data' => $request->file,
'agree_data' => $request->agree
 );

  Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use ($request,$data){
  $message->to('pipo@gmail.com', 'piooi')->subject('Send mail ' . $request->name);
  $message->from($request->email, $request->name);
  if ( isset($data['file_data']))

              {
                $message->attach($data['file_data']->getRealPath(), array(
                    'as'    => $data['file_data']->getClientOriginalName(),
                    'mime'  => $data['file_data']->getMimeType()));
                  }
         });
                  Session::flash('success', 'Mail spedita con sucesso');
 }
    }
```

I put the piece of the form in question:

```
<form class="text-left form-email"action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Curriculum Vitae:</span>
             </div>
             <div class="custom-file">
               <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file"
                 aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
               <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Seleziona il file</label>
             </div>
           </div>
```

the error that gives the summit is the following:

> local.ERROR: Call to a member function getRealPath() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0):

Comment: The error message is telling you that the method 'getRealPath()' is being called on a null object. It looks like you are using that here: $data['file_data']->getRealPath(). if you dd($data['file_data']), do you see what you would expect to see? is it an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your mail part to this and see if it works

```
Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use ($request,$data){
    $message->to('pipo@gmail.com', 'piooi')->subject('Send mail ' . $request->name);
    $message->from($request->email, $request->name);
    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $message->attach($request->file->getRealPath(), array(
            'as'    => $request->file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'mime'  => $request->file->getMimeType())
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: so send the email without attach

Comment: the problem was the calendar script changing the status of the form, now I would like to send multiple emails as I modify it?